# OS X Server not showing in Windows Vista Shared

Tags: windows-vista, mac-osx

I have OS X Server installed. I am using Window Vista on a PC.
But on my network I can't see the OS X server. But I can see other Mac computers in shared but not OS X server.

I am able to ping the IP.

What should I do?

Comment: Please qualify "I can't see it". As in, you cannot connect to file shares on it? You cannot see when you browse the network? Elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

On the OS X server you should disable the builtin Firewall (if you have it enabled) and enable the Windows file sharing service in Server Admin.

Comment: There is no problem with OSX as all other computer on netwrok can see it

Comment: even ubutntu can see the server but not windows vista

Comment: It's very possible that OSX is electing itself master browser of the network, there is an option in a configuration file to turn this off, which will let the Vista box be the master browser and will likely fix your issue. However, updates to OSX may reset this behavior. I would also disable the Vista firewall, as a troubleshooting step.